# MySQL charset conversion

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding, internationalization

I have a database in which all text fields and tables have 'utf8' specified explicitly as default character set, however data in this database is stored as 'cp1257'. I can display symbols only when I use `SET NAMES 'cp1257'` or `\C cp1257`. Trying to display them without those instructions fails, because it tries to fetch data as 'utf8' (?). What could I do to get all data (perhaps a backup) of database as 'cp1257' and put it back as valid 'utf8' ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert them first to binary field and then set the field as cp1257. This way MySQL will know in which charset the field is stored:

```
ALTER TABLE CHANGE `field` `field` BLOB;
ALTER TABLE CHANGE `field` `field` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'cp1257';
```

If you want to change way how data are stored, you can now convert the field to any charset (MySQL will do the conversion of data in this step):

```
ALTER TABLE CHANGE `field` `field` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have many tables like this, can I do the conversion on a whole database without having to convert each table (and even each field) ?

Comment: You can't do this in SQL, but you can definitely script it in something else what would just generate the SQL queries.

Comment: Seems a bit complicated and first line doesn't work, perhaps because `field` is used with KEY(..). I am thinking about a trick with mysqldump, I've successfully exported my database to .sql file and I can even see valid characters with editor (if I set utf-8 encoding option). So file is unicode.. How could I import the data as it is now ? Importing back in usual way (mysql -u user -p database < sqlfile.sql) gives the same.

Comment: If the field was originally `VARCHAR`, you should rather use `VARBINARY` as a type for conversion.